# How to run xUnit tests using Mono (.net core 3.0+ or .net standard 2.1 required)

Tags: mono, xunit, blazor

How can we run our xUnit tests on the Mono framework?

...

We've got a bunch of xunit tests for our .NET Standard 2.1 and .NET Core 3.1 projects.

Our website is using client-side blazor (still an experimental framework).  It uses ***mono*** in the browser.

Some financial calculations were incorrect on the website, leading us to discover this: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/19863

Since our xUnit tests in visual studio run as .net core apps instead of mono, it was not discovered through testing.

...

Googling around shows an approach using the xunit console runner, but it does not support .net core 3.1 apps or any framework supporting .net standard 2.1 (it seems out of date).  I haven't found any other approach.  Any ideas?

Comment: Did you consider e2e tests using selenuim ?

Comment: Of course we'll use a front-end testing suite too, but it's outside the scope of this question for now.  Thanks though!

Comment: I know but blazor client-side use mono WASM, it run in the browser, it's not the full mono framework. You should write an e2e test for this specif issue.